# CakePHP 1.3 FormHelper Input "Selected" Not Working

Tags: php, html, cakephp

First, the $questions array:

```
    Array
    (
        [2] => How much do you like cheese?
        [3] => How much do you like cake?
        [6] => Is this question successfully added?
    )
```

Here's how I'm trying to use it in the input:

```
   <td>
       <?php echo $this->Form->input('question', array(
             'options' => $questions,
             'selected' => $questions[6], 
             'name' => 'data[ResponseActions]['.$responseAction['responses_actions']['id'].'][question_id]')); 
       ?>
   </td>
```

However, whenever the page is rendered, element 2 is always selected by default. Does anyone know why I'm having this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `selected` option expects the key, not the value.

```
'selected' => 6
```

Comment: Cool. I'll try this when I get home. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: should't it be 'default' to preserve the form after validation errors? with `selected` it will always jump back to the value 6 I believe

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Array
    (
        '2' => 'How much do you like cheese?'
        '3' => 'How much do you like cake?'
        '6' => 'Is this question successfully added?'
    )

<?php echo $this->Form->input('question', array(
             'options' => $questions,
             'selected' => '6', 
             'name' => 'data[ResponseActions]['.$responseAction['responses_actions']['id'].'][question_id]')); 
       ?>
```